# Template only showing up in top left corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, innerhtml

I am trying to use templates in .html and when I load a template in, it is only showing up in a small area in the top left corner and giving me a scroll wheel to move around the small box. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, the code works perfectly fine in its own .html but when I try to use a template it doesn't.

template.html

```
    <style>
  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navbar-item {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .navbar-item:hover {
    color: #eee;
  }
</style>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-item">Home</div>
  <div class="navbar-item">About</div>
  <div class="navbar-item">Contact</div>
</nav>
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Navbar Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar-container"></div>

    <script>
      var navbarContainer = document.getElementById('navbar-container');
      navbarContainer.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="template.html"></object>';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The height of your navbar is too large - it is oveflowing the viewport. Change the height of your navbar to 50px;

Comment: @RandyCasburn even if I change that, the menu is still much too small not even coming close to the width of my screen

Comment: Show that outcome with [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)